# How to make Canvas Unit/ Unity Units consistent size.

Tags: unity, gui

I'm making an application within unity that leans heavily on UI but whenever I create new UI Elements they appear huge and I have to make a lot of logical concessions to get it to look normal. is there a way to change the Canvas pixels/unit value in the editor? A lot of the people with similar problems I see just are told "That's just how unity works, don't worry about it." but there has to be a better solution.

Comment: There are a dozen or so different settings and scripts that all conspire in determining how UI is sized. Because there are many different scaling behaviours that game creators might want to use, under many different running conditions, and as a general-purpose engine Untiy tries to support as many of those as it can. To tell you how to configure all of them for your particular goals, we'll need a clearer picture of what "look normal" means for your case. Can you give us some concrete examples, and an overview of how your project is set up so far?

Comment: fullscreen with a single panel up top with a horizontal group of icons and dialog windows that pop up to add a new icon. those are the only features. when i create a new text element for an input label or the like, i have to change the width/height properties to extremely low values (1-10) and toggle "best fit" and change to horizontal/vertical overflow for the text to even show up.